# Ubuntu boot stuck at "ok started gnome display manager"

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I'm on 19.04, Lenovo yoga laptop. I have an encrypted disk. When I logged out, the screen flickered (as it has done before),so I had to press the power off key.

Now the boot is stuck at: ok started gnome display manager.

Disconcertingly, it doesn't seem to be possible to get into safe boot or to get a login prompt.

Neither shift not ESC works while the Lenovo logo shows. The logo shows only very briefly (does that mean uefi? Sure that mean shift won't work?)

During the book sequence, ESC switches between graphical and non-graphical.

However, alt+ctrl+fn+f1 to f12 doesn't work to get a terminal. Neither does alt+fn+f1 through f12.

Ctrl+alt+fn+prtscr followed by any other character seems to get a sysrq prompt, but for all of the options it seems to say "option not recognised". (Though I have no idea what sysrq actually is....)

It would be amazing if one of you can help....

**Edit.** For some reason, I just got a full boot (despite having tried to boot several times previously). The only difference is that I left the screen with "ok started gnome display manager" for around 20 mins while looking for a solution, and then rebooted again, trying to get into the bios.

I would still massively appreciate some feedback on how to get into the terminal or safe boot, so that I can deal with this or similar things in the future.

Comment: No, I am not. However, I wonder whether that is a configuration issue with my laptop rather than lack of response to keyboard?  None of alt+ctrl+fn+f1 to f12 work.